# Use Cloud Function download a JSON file from URL then upload to a Cloud Storage bucket, status 200 but JSON file uploaded is only 20 bytes and empty

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use the cloud function to download a JSON file from here: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts? then upload it to Cloud Storage bucket.

Log of function execution seems fine, the status returns 200. However, **the JSON file uploaded to the bucket is only 20 Bytes and it is empty** (while the original file is ~27 KB)

---

So please help me if I missed something, there is code and logs:

### index.js

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    
exports.writeToBucket = (req, res) => {
    const http = require('http');
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    const file = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/post.json");
    const request = http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?", function(response) {
      response.pipe(file);
    });
    
    
    console.log('file downloaded');
    
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
    const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    
    // Creates a client
    const storage = new Storage();
    const bucketName = 'tft-test-48c87.appspot.com';
    const filename = '/tmp/post.json';

    // Uploads a local file to the bucket
    storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
      gzip: true,
      metadata: {
        cacheControl: 'no-cache',
      },
    });

    res.status(200).send(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
    
};
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/storage": "^3.0.3"
    }
}
```

### Result:

[image]

### Log:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by [@DazWilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin), there are issues with asynchronous code. You must wait for `onfinish()` to trigger and then proceed. Also the `upload()` method returns a promise too. Try refactoring your function in `async-await` syntax as shown below:

```js
exports.writeToBucket = async (req, res) => {
  const http = require('http');
  const fs = require('fs');

  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    
  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucketName = 'tft-test-48c87.appspot.com';
  const filename = '/tmp/post.json';  

  await downloadJson()

  // Uploads a local file to the bucket
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
    gzip: true,
    metadata: {
      cacheControl: 'no-cache',
    },
  });

  res.status(200).send(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
}

const downloadJson = async () => {
 const Axios = require('axios')
 const fs = require("fs")
 const writer = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/post.json")
 const response = await Axios({
   url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
   method: 'GET',
   responseType: 'stream'
 })
 response.data.pipe(writer)
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   writer.on('finish', resolve)
   writer.on('error', reject)
 })
}
```

This example uses Axios but you can do the same with `http`.

Do note that you can directly upload the fetched JSON as a file like this:

```js
exports.writeToBucket = async (req, res) => {
  const Axios = require("axios");
  const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucketName = "tft-test-48c87.appspot.com";
  const filename = "/tmp/post.json";

  const { data } = await Axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

  const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file("file.json");
  const contents = JSON.stringify(data);
  await file.save(contents);

  res.status(200).send(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
};
```

You can read more about the `save()` method in the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I tried with Axios method and it seems to be missing `url: ` [here](https://i.imgur.com/6EmoawN.jpg) causing it to fail to deploy. So I tried adding `url:` then successfully deploying but when run function, it gives `fs is not defined` error like [this](https://i.imgur.com/tZGKfYg.jpg).
About "directly upload the fetched JSON", could you pls give me the full code? I'm a complete newbie :P

Comment: @Kel I've updated my answer. Thanks for catching the missing `url:`, you just need to add `const fs = require("fs")` as in updated answer after importing axios.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much xD. Btw, I also want to try the HTTP method as you note if it's simpler, however, there seems to be an error in my code [here](https://i.imgur.com/9HaidyC.jpg), could you pls check it for me, or if you can edit the full code in your answer I appreciate it

Comment: @Kel I've updated the code snippet with that method.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, your code works perfectly with `HTTP TRIGGER`, however when I change TRIGGER to `Cloud Pub/Sub` there is an Error: `function execution failed. Details: res.status is not a function` [IMG](https://i.imgur.com/DKjAJ4J.png), can you pls help me again?

Comment: @Kel that's correct, you can't return a response from a background function. They are not triggered by any user. You should terminate them by returning a promise. I'd recommend asking a new question for that with the minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a write stream to get the URL data, fetch the URL, await the response to resolve, call the appropriate response.toJson() method.

Personally, I prefer to use Fetch and Axios over `http` as they are cleaner to work with. But with Nodes `http` you can do the following:

```js
https.get(url,(res) => {
    let body = "";

    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on("end", () => {
        try {
            let json = JSON.parse(body);
            // do something with JSON
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
        };
    });

}).on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
});
```

Once you have that, you can pass it directly to a storage method as a data blob or byte array.

```js
byte[] byteArray = resultJson.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```